# how to create angular 4 app in gradle inside src/main/webapp eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, angular

I have been working on an Angular 4 project in Gradle eclipse, for Webservices support. But When I create an angular app it's creating a separate folder. I want to create in inside the src/main/web app. I don't know separate or inside the Gradle project. I am in confusion about the folder structure. Like Gradle angular separate or Angular inside the Gradle.

My requirement is creating a web dynamic project in angular 4 in eclipse.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i want to know angular 4 project should be inside the gradle project or out side the gradle project?